# Extract data from Word where there is a vertically merged cell to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to extract specific data from a Word file to an Excel file using VBA.

My VBA code extracts data except if the Word file has a vertically merged cell in the table.

I cannot unmerge each Word file since I have a lot of Word files.

Word file where I tried to extract data form the red arrow. One cell is vertically merged in the blue circle.
[image]

I got error

> vertically merge cells

The Excel file where I tried to put the information extracted from Word file.
[image]

```vb
Sub extractData()

Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim sh As Worksheet

wd.Visible = True

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\abcd.docx")
Set tbls = doc.Tables
Set sh = ActiveSheet

i = 3
sh.Cells(3, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(7).Cells(1).Range.Text)

doc.Close
wd.Quit
Set doc = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Needs a screenshot to make the problem clearer...

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. If all you need is to find the correct cell address to use in your code, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-tables/26997-identifying-table-cell-addresses.html

Comment: I have updated the post with link to screenshot. in summary i got the error message "vertically merge cell" in word table

Comment: hello, anyone can advice? :)